# how to set cookies in angular that get from database

Tags: angular, http

I want to display username after login successful.
I am using Nodejs Mysql server for backend and angular for frontend

Comment: your question cannot be answered. we need more informations. What are you using for the login? how does the user log-in? also show some code, that helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) to call api in angular.

You can use [rxjs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable) library, making an observable for username. And that's it, it works almost like cookies or `SESSION` in php. You create subscription to subscribe that variable return from api everytime you wish to use it, just like a cookies.

Can't provide much sample code cause it requires more specific requirement.